# Why is there an Authentication error whilst using pymongo authentication?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

When I am trying to authenticate mongodb by using pymongo, it shows the below error,

> command SON([('saslStart', 1), ('mechanism', 'SCRAM-SHA-1'),
>   ('autoAuthorize', 1), ('payload',
>   Binary('n,,n=user,r=Mzk1NDU4ODUwNzU4', 0))]) on namespace
>   the_database.$cmd failed: Authentication failed.

**My authentication code**

```
client.fw_mongo.authenticate('user', 'password' )
```

***fw_mongo is my mongodb name***

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Your error and your code sample don't match: are you authenticating against "fw_mongo" or against "the_database"?

Comment: @ A. Jesse Jiryu Davis fw_mongo is my database name

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but your password is not the same as you configured MongoDB with.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
Client = MongoClient("mongodb://" + username + ":" + password + "server_details")

def collection_object():
    db = Client.db_name
    collection = db.collection_name
    return collection
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: It does not work still gives same error. Python 2.7 and pymongo 2.8.1